# Silverlight 4.0 databinding with custom (netTiers) business objects

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I am attempting to bind data from a netTiers BO architecture to a Silverlight 4.0 grid using VS 2010. I have only seen examples using RIA with Entity Framework. How do I wire up RIA services to a custom BO/DAL layer? I have also tried adding the Silverlight as a WCF Service template which did not bind the data either. It appears as though the service, whether RIA, WCF Silverlight Template, or vanilla WCF is not getting called.

Comment: Need more information.  Code sample?

Answer (score 0):

I found it very hard to do non EF with RIA so far...I am still learning, but I did read that you have to connect the SVC endopoint into the client. I have used nettiers for several projects, but unfortunately they are not keeping up with more recent developments in the .net world and its making it harder and harder to wedge it into an application. Depending on your timeframe, you may be better off just using EF and Ria Services. Its different than nettiers, but it does a lot of the same behind the scenes stuff and its super easy to setup.